# Phasor format vs time domain format question

Tags: rms, phasor

I have a quick question regarding phasor format vs time domain format. Whenever we write in the phasor format, the magnitude that we use must be the RMS value for voltage/current, correct? Then we convert back to phase value when writing in the time domain format.

Also, does this apply to the power equation as well, P = V·I·cos(θ), where the voltage and current that we use must be the RMS values, as P is the real power?

Comment: Do you mean *convert back to **peak** value when writing in the time domain format*

Comment: Yes when we go back to peak value for time domain format